# Facebook video on website , hide header part

Tags: html, facebook, iframe

Implemented the Facebook video on website,but there appears the Facebook header in its iframe.
How to hide that header?
Can anyone help me in it?
[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/157171235015171/

Comment: i will check that .